# Visual Studio always rebuilds when debugging Xamarin Android Project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

When debugging/deploying Xamarin Android applications in Visual Studio, the solution is rebuild **every** time. Even if source code is unchanged.

I used Xamarin studio before and this didn't happen.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Xamarin 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Visual Studio settings. Tools -> Options -> Projects and solutions -> Build and Run.